# Error in array created in loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I've been trying to make an array from a loop.

When I run the program the program prints all the values I need, but when I look in the variable explorer or say `print new1` again it only prints the last value.

I've checked and the value it assigns to the array is the last value of `i` and `j` but I need it to make an array of all the values.

Comment: code:for i, j in (Datafile:
    if i < 1e4: 
        new1 = array([i, j])
        young1= new1[::2]
        young2 = new1[1::2]

Comment: Please post you code so that it will be easy to help you

Answer (score -1):

you should be doing:

```
new1.append(array([i,j]))
```

instead of:

```
new1 = array([i,j]) # this replaces new1 as a new array each time
```

and make sure to initialize `new1` as a list with:

```
new1 = [] #make sure this is before your for loop
```

Comment: `array` is not a built-in type (or at least, `array.array` doesn't follow the interface you're using). Trying to answer a question before it provides enough information to understand the real mistake (they could just as easily be reinitializing to the empty `list` over and over, or assigning to `somelist[0]` or whatever).